# new users : use latex?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, new-users

I often edit and comment new users' questions with

> Use latex (click on edit to see what I typed)

I wonder if it is possible to detect when a new user is posting a question without using latex, and show him a message about using latex, clicking on edit, and simple examples $\scriptstyle\sum, \int,\prod_{n=1}^\infty, \sin^2(x^a), \sqrt{2}, \implies \ldots$

Comment: I will just point out that a message which contains *a link* to Mathjax tutorial is already shown when a user posts their first question. See here: [Show “how to ask” advice before a new user asks a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21512) and [An auto-comment on first questions that motivates sharing doubts and thoughts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22179#22180).

Comment: I think your post-specific improvements are likely to be more convincing evidence to a new user of the benefit of learning to use $\LaTeX$ than any generic auto-post.

Comment: It is unfortunate that MathJax is getting called LaTeX. If someone masters MathJax (which is what is used here; LaTeX is not) and then mistakenly thinks they have learned LaTeX, they will experience an unpleasant shock if they encounter actual LaTeX and find out they don't know it.